# Users not created correctly in Django test case

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

Im running a simple unit test on getting tastypie API keys from users. To do this, I am trying to create a new user in the test case who I authenticate and fetch their API key. 
The code for the test case is as follows:

```
def setup(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='test1',password='pass')


 def test_user_api_key_fetch(self):
    user = User.objects.get(username='test1')
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/login/',{'username':'test1','password':'pass'})
    print response.content
    self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 200)
```

This test fails at the first line, asserting that no user can be found. I have checked the `User.objects.all()` and it is empty. The problem is not solved by changing `setup()` to include `user.save()` or using `User.objects.create_user()` instead. Why cant this user be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is not being created, because the `setup` method is not being run. It should be called `setUp` - note the upper-case `U`. See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp).